# PHP Recordset Returning "Error: Query Was Empty"

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code written that when it runs I get "Error: Query was empty" no matter what the SQL query is. I know the SQL being generated is good because if I paste it into the SQL database it returns rows. The PHP code for the recordset has been pasted from other pages that work just fine so I'm failing to see where the bug is.

case 4: //check to see if user has previously loaded a checklist

```
    $mySQL = "SELECT * FROM tools_userChklists WHERE chklistID = '" . $_GET['chklistID'] . "'";
            echo $mySQL;
    $query_rsChecklists = $mySQL;
    $rsChecklists = mysql_query($query_rsChecklists) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsChecklists = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsChecklists);
    $totalRows_rsChecklists = mysql_num_rows($rsChecklists);

    if ($totalRows_rsChecklists <> 0){
        //the user has already opened this checklist
        $_SESSION['redirectorAction'] = "";
        $_SESSION['redirectorAction'] = "Location: actions.php?action=5&chklistID=" . $_GET['chklistID'];
    }else{
        //the user has never opened this checklist
        $_SESSION['redirectorAction'] = "";
        $_SESSION['redirectorAction'] = "Location: actions.php?action=6&chklistID=" . $_GET['chklistID'];
    }
break;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$row_rsChecklists is the result resource and you have numrows on rsChecklists.  i suggest using real simple words like 'row' for shortblock work.

Comment: As mentioned, I have been using this same format code for recordsets for a few years now without issues. I'll give it a try but I'm not too confident it will make a difference. Thanks for the input though.